# trouble opening solution on VirtualBox network share mapped as drive

Tags: visual-studio, virtualbox

Visual Studio solution on a mapped VirtualBox drive gives odd error message when opened in Visual Studio on a VM.

I'm getting an odd error message when opening a solution in Visual Studio. The wrinkle here is that I'm running OSX 10.13.6, and then Windows 10 in a VirtualBox VM. My source code/solution is located on my Mac's filesystem, and Visual Studio is installed on the Win10 VM (long story; I've run into other difficulties running the solution with OSX native Visual Studio and trying this as an alternative).

Let's say the solution is on my Mac at /Users/tom/development/myproject/foo.sln. On that host, I've mapped /Users/tom/development/ to name "devstuff" as a VirtualBox shared folder, automount/permanent.

On the Win10 guest, I've then mapped \VBOXSVR\devstuff\ to drive letter Z:. When I go to Z: in Windows Explorer I see the myproject directory as I would expect. I can read/write files in that directory from the Win10 guest OS, so I think my sharing/mapping/mounting is set up correctly.

On the Win10 guest OS, I then launch Visual Studio (v 15.9.5) and go to "File | Open | Project/Solution"; I then browse to Z:\myproject\foo.sln. When I open it, I get the following error:

> Creation of the virtual directory http://localhost:49267 failed with
>   the error: Filename:
>   \\?\Z:\myproject.vs\config\applicationhost.config Error: Cannot read
>   configuration file. You will need to manually create this virtual
>   directory in IIS before you can open this project.

(That's backslash+backslash+questionmark+backslash+Z+colon+backslash...)

applicationhost.config does exist and I can view it from both guest and host OS. I can even open it in Visual Studio!

Why is my mapped Z: drive looking like a network share \\?\Z:\ when I open the file in Visual Studio? I assume that's why it can't find the file, but why isn't it just opening it as Z:\myproject...?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I have been hosting a secured drive with TrueCrypt for my git repository. When it is shared through VirtualBox the drive appears correctly within the file explorer but when Visual Studio is run and IIS express is attempting to run there is an error as described above; with the \?\s:...
My solution is to open the TrueCrypt encrypted drive within windows thus not sharing it through VirtualBox. This works but is not the ideal solution.
Be good to get a robust answer to this one.